# Firefox 5 - jQuery.data() - Only works on refresh

Tags: jquery, firefox, custom-data-attribute

The .data() method by jquery only seems to work when I do a refresh, not when I simply reload the page by pressing ENTER in the URL location bar.

Yet the div is there, I've logged it in console.log -- , whether on refresh or on simple enter to load the page from cache..

Has anyone seen this behavior? What could be wrong?

```
$('div.special').each(function(index) {
    console.log($(this));
    //shows clearly that data-settings is set..
    if ($(this).data('settings')) {
        console.log('got settings');
    }
});


<div class="special" data-settings='{"dataUrl": "xxx", "layout": "list" }'></div>
```

Edit: I can "solve" this by doing the following:

```
if ($(this).data('settings')) {
   var settings = $(this).data('settings');
} else if ($(this).attr('data-settings')) {
    eval('var settings = ' + $(this).attr('data-settings') + ';');
}
```

So obviously there is nothing wrong with the div or the way the data-settings is constructed, as I can access the json object perfectly fine via the eval..

Comment: Are you able to share source ?

Comment: Sorry, it's a local development project at the moment. Can't just share a single page either.

Comment: Why can you not just post the `div` and the `.data()` method

Comment: Well, I can post that, be updating in a sec.

Comment: It may just be a mistake when copying the code into the question but you are using a single quote to open the `data-settings` attribute value, and a double quote to close it.

Comment: Sorry, that was due to editing it here at stackoverflow, it was only visible for a second, didn't think anyone would catch that.

Comment: No i'm not, i removed some extra styling from the div to place it here, that's where the double quote came from, refresh the page and you'll see it correctly. The code is single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how much help I can be without seeing your soruce !!! But here is a very simple example of how the `.data()` method works (taken from the example at jquery.com) -> http://jsfiddle.net/yR3KG/

Comment: I've tried my own code on jsfiddle as well, and it works in FF5, but jsfiddle is probably interpreted differently from a normal page, right? eval() etc?

Comment: When you say it doesnt work - what do you mean ? i get "got settings" in my console log on Chrome and FF ....

Comment: I don't get the message "got settings" when I load the page again by pressing ENTER in the URL bar. I do get it when I refresh by clicking the refresh button.

Comment: I have added a way I "solved" this in the original message.. Weird stuff.

Comment: That is very very strange !!!! caching somewhere perhaps ? maybe worth reporting to jquery